# importing external js function Mongodb shell

Tags: javascript, python, shell, mongodb

I have javascript functions written in a json file:

```
functions={}
functions.a =
    function(){
        return "returned"
    }
```

I have seen on tutorials that if we import that json file I can use those functions from shell.

I am trying this to import functions

```
mongo --shell test json
```

But my functions do not work! In this circumstance what can be done?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#mongo-shell-javascript-file  `mongo db --shell test.js`

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
$ cat foo.js
functions={}
functions.a =
    function(){
        return "returned"
}
$ mongo --shell foo.js
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.0-rc0
connecting to: test
> functions.a()
returned
```